# How do I obtain summary of each unique id

Tags: r, unique, plyr

I would like to extract some summary statistics for a number of values in multiple columns. My data looks as follows

```
id                pace       type                   value      abundance 
51                (T)        (JC)                   (L)           0        
51                (T)        (JC)                   (L)           0 
51                (T)        (JC)                   (H)           0
52                (T)        (JC)                   (H)           0
52                (R)        (JC)                   (H)           0
53                (T)        (JC)                   (L)           1
53                (T)        (JC)                   (H)           1
53                (R)        (JC)                   (H)           1
53                (R)        (JC)                   (H)           1
53                (R)        (JC)                   (H)           1
54                (T)        (BC)                 <blank>         0          

54                (T)        (BC)                 <blank>         0 
54                (T)        (BC)                 <blank>         0
```

and I am hoping for something like this

```
id    ptype       (T)    (R)        (L)      (H)     abundance
51     (JC)        3      0          2        1         0
52     (JC)        1      1          0        2         0
53     (JC)        2      3          1        4         1
54     (BC)        3      0          0        0         0
```

I have begun writing some code:

```
for (i in levels(df$id))
{
  extract.event <- df[df$id==i,]# To identify each section
ppace <- table(extract.event$pace) #count table of pace 
ptype <- extract.event$type[1] # extract the first line to be the type
nvalues <- table(extract.event$value) #count table of value
nabundance <- min(extract.event$abundance) #minimum of abundance

d <- cbind(ppace,ptype,forbeh,nvalues,nabundance)
```

but I am running into problems merging the values, especially when the nabundance prints out an empty table. I would prefer not to extract by name as there are so many names in the data frame. Any ideas? I thought it might be something to do with plyr package, but still not sure...

Thanks,

Grace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to rewrite your data.frame (for future reference please paste the results of dput because we hate rewriting your data) but here is my attempt. I'm guessing you are looking for something along the lines of the aggregate function:

```
df <- data.frame(id = as.factor(c(51,51,51,52,52,53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54)), 
      pace = c("(T)","(T)","(T)","(T)","(R)","(T)","(T)","(R)","(R)","(R)","(T)","(T)","(T)"), 
      type = c("(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(JC)","(BC)","(BC)","(BC)"), value = c("(L)","(L)","(H)","(H)","(H)","(L)","(H)","(H)","(H)","(H)","<blank>","<blank>","<blank>"), 
      abundance = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))

smallnames <- colnames(do.call("cbind",as.list(aggregate(cbind(value, pace, abundance) ~ id + type, data = lapply(df, as.character), table))))
smallnames
[1] "id"      "type"    "(H)"     "(L)"     "<blank>" "(R)"     "(T)"     "0"      
[9] "1"

df.new <- do.call("data.frame", as.list(aggregate(cbind(value, pace, abundance) ~ id + type, data = lapply(df, as.character), table)))
colnames(df.new) <- smallnames
df.new$abundance <- df.new$`1`
df.new
  id type (H) (L) <blank> (R) (T) 0 1 abundance
1 54 (BC)   0   0       3   0   3 3 0         0
2 51 (JC)   1   2       0   0   3 3 0         0
3 52 (JC)   2   0       0   1   1 2 0         0
4 53 (JC)   4   1       0   3   2 0 5         5

df.final <- df.new[, -which(colnames(df.new) %in% c("<blank>","0","1"))]
df.final
  id type (H) (L) (R) (T) abundance
1 54 (BC)   0   0   0   3         0
2 51 (JC)   1   2   0   3         0
3 52 (JC)   2   0   1   1         0
4 53 (JC)   4   1   3   2         5
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for or if you have trouble with it.

Comment: See edits where part2 is similar to your desired data frame output

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(value, pace, abundance) ~ id + type, data=lapply(df, as.character), table)` seems to almost get there a bit easier

Comment: It's a neat line of code but you'll notice once you add abundance, you deal with counts of 0 and 1. Plus, aggregate really leaves a data frame with matrices inside of it. Part1 Uses do.call + cbind on an as.list aggregate object to just make the names more clear (as asked) and properly formatted (a simple data.frame). Part2 (while ugly looking) simply forces things to look as OP asked. I do like the use of cbind though, +1

Comment: yeah, youre right it would need to have `do.call(...` at the front. From there expected outcome for the abundance it seems as if they want `1` if an id has any values and zero otherwise, so this will be easy to get by separating out abundance. (ps i think you can do `do.call(data.frame`

Comment: Hi @EvanFriedland, yes this is what I'm looking for, thanks! I have been able to somewhat adapt it to my data.. The only thing is, it is not aggregating the values inside the columns it is just giving the count of the total column for each id. So for example, for id 51 the value column = 3 rather than creating 2 columns H and L... any ideas? Could it be something to do with the structure of the data? My id is a factor

Comment: See my edits, I changed it all up, including incorporating the great advice from user2957945. I also corrected abundance, as I realized it was counting zeros instead of counting only 1s.